# Javascript Array Sum

Tags: javascript

How I can sum up the values filled in unitprice array using javascript
Here is my html.

```
   <td>
       <input type="text" style="width: 60px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);" maxlength="4" id="unitprice" name="unitprice[]">
   </td>
   <td>
       <input type="text" style="width: 60px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);" maxlength="4" id="unitprice" name="unitprice[]">
   </td>
```

Comment: IDs have to be **unique**! (and yes, you can)

Comment: Use `class` attributes instead of `id` attributes. (You cannot have more then one element with the same ID on the page.)

Comment: ok if I make IDs unique then How can I further do it ? Please remember that unitprice is dynamic like I click on Add new row and it create another unitprice. So I need their sum.

Comment: like @Šime Vidas .. use unique classes ... you can have as many classes as you want on an element

Comment: @Faizan All IDs on a page must be unique. To workaround this you can use a CSS class as a marker or a unique attribute. Example you can declare `<input type="text" unitpricemarker="" name="unitprice"/>` You can now select all such fields using jQuery - `$('input[unitpricemarker]')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your HTML to use `class` instead of `id` (`id` must be unique):

```
<td>
    <input type="text" 
        style="width: 60px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);" maxlength="4" 
        class="unitprice" name="unitprice[]">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" 
        style="width: 60px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);"
            maxlength="4" class="unitprice" name="unitprice[]">
</td>
```

Then you can total via JavaScript (using jQuery `.each()` function):

```
var totalUnitPrice = 0;

$('.unitprice').each(function(index) {
    totalUnitPrice += parseInt($(this).val()); // parse the value to an Integer (otherwise it'll be concatenated as string) or use parseFloat for decimals
  });
```

Comment: `var sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);` is faster than jQuery's each().

Comment: Or even shorter 
`var sum = reduce((a, b)=>a + b, 0);`

Answer (score 40):

If you can get the values in an array, you don't have to use jQuery to sum them.  You can use methods already present on the array object to do the work.

Arrays have a .reduce() method.
Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Array.reduce accepts a function as an argument that acts as an accumulator callback.  The accumulator function accepts 4 arguments (previousValue, currentValue, index, array).  You only need 2 of them to sum.  Those 2 arguments are previousValue and currentValue.

```
var sampleArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var sum = sampleArray.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue){
    return currentValue + previousValue;
});
```

If you are faced with a compatibility issue where the target environment doesn't support ECMAScript 5 or above additions, use the prototype definition defined in the MDN article linked. (Appended below)

```
if (!Array.prototype.reduce) {
    Array.prototype.reduce = function reduce(accumulator){
    if (this===null || this===undefined) throw new TypeError("Object is null or undefined");
    var i = 0, l = this.length >> 0, curr;
    if(typeof accumulator !== "function") // ES5 : "If IsCallable(callbackfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception."
        throw new TypeError("First argument is not callable");
    if(arguments.length < 2) {
        if (l === 0) throw new TypeError("Array length is 0 and no second argument");
        curr = this[0];
        i = 1; // start accumulating at the second element
    }
    else
        curr = arguments[1];
    while (i < l) {
        if(i in this) curr = accumulator.call(undefined, curr, this[i], i, this);
        ++i;
    }
    return curr;
    };
}
```

Comment: What i was asking for. OP's original title is a little misleading.

Comment: This answer deserves a lot more recognition. Thanks derenard.

Comment: Use lambda: `var sum = sampleArray.reduce((e, i) => e + i)`

Answer (score 2):

```
function getSum(){
    var ups = document.getElementsByName('unitprice[]'), sum = 0, i;
    for(i = ups.length; i--;)
        if(ups[i].value)
            sum += parseInt(ups[i].value, 10);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You can also write the `for` loop as `for(i = ups.length; i--;)`

Comment: @Felix Yea thanks that's a lot cleaner. I'm not sure why I wrote it the way I did haha

Answer (score 1):

//arr it's your array input vlaue `array.push(input.val())`

```
function array_sum(arr){
    var sum = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        sum += parseInt(arr[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `<input>`s unique ids like this:

```
<input type="text" id="unitprice_1">
<input type="text" id="unitprice_2">
<input type="text" id="unitprice_3">
```

Then compute the sum:

```
var i = 1;
var sum = 0;
var input;
while( ( input = document.getElementById( 'unitprice_'+i ) ) !== null ) {
    sum += parseInt( input.value );
    ++i;
}
alert( sum );
```